# count if event occurs per city

Tags: python, pandas, events, count

I am trying to count how often an event occurs before another event occurs per city. To be more specific I am trying to count how often event number 21 occurrs before 2, and the other way around.

The dataset looks like this

```py
import pandas as pd

data = { 'city': ['Amsterdam', 'Vienna', 'Paris', 'Paris',  'Istanbul', 'Istanbul','Delhi', 'London', 'London', 'Barcelona', 'Barcelona'], 
        'date': [ '2022-09-01T11:34:53', '2022-09-01T13:37:37', '2022-09-01 10:44:22.000', '2022-09-01T10:39:33', '2022-09-01 16:18:24.000', '2022-09-01T16:15:14', '2022-09-01T13:28:33', '2022-09-01 15:50:54.000', '2022-09-01T15:51:07', '2022-09-01 12:24:26.000','2022-09-01T12:24:07' ], 
        'year': [ '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022', '2022','2022' ],
        'month': [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 ],
        'hour': [ 11,13,11,10,17,16,13,16,16,13,12 ],
        'eventcode': [ 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J','J' ],
        'eventnumber': [ '21', '21', '2', '21', '2', '21', '21', '2', '21', '2','21' ]}

df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['city', 'date', 'year',  'month', 'hour', 'eventcode','eventnumber' ])
print (df)
```

In this dataset, when looking at the city and date, event 2 occurs 1 time before event 21, and event 21 occurs 3 times before event 2.

The code below works for counting the number of occurences of event 21 happening before 2. But when I switch the 2 and 21 in the code, it results in an infinite loop...

```py
bc=np.array(df['city'])
un_bc,bc_index,bc_count=np.unique(bc,return_counts=True,return_index=True)
new_df=pd.DataFrame()
count=0

for i,j in zip(bc_index,bc_count):
    j=j+i-1
    while i+1 <= j:
        if df.iat[i,7]==21 and df.iat[i+1,7]==2:
            count +=1
            new_df=new_df.append(df[i:i+2])
        i +=1
        
print(count)
```

Code above works, code below does not.

```py
for i,j in zip(bc_index,bc_count):
    j=j+i-1
    while i+1 <= j:
        if df.iat[i,7]==2 and df.iat[i+1,7]==21:
            count +=1
            new_df=new_df.append(df[i:i+2])
        i +=1
        
print(count)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you tried that created an infinite loop.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the code I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be as follows:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

res = df.sort_values('date').astype({'eventnumber':int})\
    .groupby('city')['eventnumber'].diff().value_counts()
res.index = res.index.map({-19:'21_before_2', 19: '2_before_21'})

print(res)

21_before_2    3
2_before_21    1
Name: eventnumber, dtype: int64
```

Or, if you don't want to turn `df['date']` into `datetime`, use `.sort_values(['year',  'month', 'hour'])`.

**Explanation**

- First, use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to turn date strings into datetime.
- Next, 1) sort the `df` on `date` (using [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)), 2) turn `eventnumber` strings into `ints` (using [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)), 3) apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `city`, 4) retrieve [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), and 5) retrieve [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).
- The result will be a count for `-19` (21 before 2) and `19` (2 before 21), with all cities with just one value being dropped. These values will end up as the index, so we can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to assign the appropriate labels.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `pandas` solution, but one way is to create a default dictionary of the list of events per city, and then count occurrences of one event before the other.

```
from collections import defaultdict
events_by_city = defaultdict(list)
for city, event_num in zip(data['city'], map(int, data['eventnumber'])):
    events_by_city[city].append(event_num)
```

The default dictionary looks like;

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Amsterdam': [21],
             'Vienna': [21],
             'Paris': [2, 21],
             'Istanbul': [2, 21],
             'Delhi': [21],
             'London': [2, 21],
             'Barcelona': [2, 21]})
```

Next you can count for the event that you want;

```
print(sum(1 for events in events_by_city.values() if events[0] == 21 and 2 in events))
```

Output

```
0
```

In this case you're counting occurrences in the default dictionary of the first item being `21` and also `2` being in the events list.

As you can see from the default dict, this doesn't actually ever occur, 21 never actually precedes 2 in any list, because all cities that have 21 as the first event number don't have an event number 2.

However, reversing events;

```
print(sum(1 for events in events_by_city.values() if events[0] == 2 and 21 in events))
```

Output

```
4
```

If you want to relax the criterion that both events must occur in then drop the last `if` condition, ie `and 2 in events` in the first case.

Edit to address the comment of @Lucas M. Uriarte and demonstrate the efficiency of the accepted answer.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime 

events_by_city = defaultdict(list)
for city, event_num, date_time in zip(data['city'], map(int, data['eventnumber']), map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.replace('.000','').replace('T',' '), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), data['date'])):
    events_by_city[city].append((event_num, date_time))

print(sum(1 for events in events_by_city.values() if sorted(events, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0] == 21 and 2 in [event[0] for event in events]))
```

Comment: I think he means by date not order. In the dataframe there is date column